# Regex replace slash with backslash inside #include double quotes

Tags: c++, regex

I want to replace slash with backslash inside #include double quotes like this.

**Before**

```
#include "Monster.h"
#include "ItemManager.h"
#include "Skil/Server/Manager/Skillmanager.h"
#include "Quest/QuestEvent.h"
#include "AES/AES.h"
#include "Trigger/Timer.h"

// Timer Class
CTimer::CTimer()
{
    printf("Minute / Second");
    printf("\t%2d:%2d\n", tMinute, tSecond);
}
```

**After**

```
#include "Monster.h"
#include "ItemManager.h"
#include "Skil\Server\Manager\Skillmanager.h"
#include "Quest\QuestEvent.h"
#include "AES\AES.h"
#include "Trigger\Timer.h"

// Timer Class
CTimer::CTimer()
{
    printf("Minute / Second");
    printf("\t%2d:%2d\n", tMinute, tSecond);
}
```

I want to replace slash in #include tag only, not replace slash in printf tag and comment tag.

What is regex that I use to search?

Thanks you.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? AFAIK, the `/` should work on Windows.

Comment: I know that work on Windows, but I want to clean my source code and I like to include with backslash instead of slash. Thanks :)

Comment: This "cleaning" makes your code non-portable. So I'd call it dirtying.  And what have you tried already? You don't even really need a regex here, "string starts with foo" can be done very cheaply.

Comment: Sorry, but I like to use backslash instead of slash. It's my coding style. And you can see in Windows, the all path in Windows use backslash, such as cmd, explorer. I would like to use like the same as Windows. Thanks you. :)

Comment: @StdAfx _'such as cmd, explorer'_ That's a big difference as having backslashes appearing in `#include` statements, where I definitely wouldn't recommend using them. If that's your coding style (or other's), it's simply _bad style_ IMHO.

Comment: A consistent solution would be somewhat trickier than only a regexp. You can comment out `#include` via `/* ... */` comments. So you would have to check whether you are in a comment first. But, maybe, you do not care or want to replace also include paths within comments. In this case, what do you do if someone has commented out an include via line comments `//`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks you for you recommend. :)

Comment: @Tobias I didn't have commented out an include anywhere in my source code. That's not my problem. Thanks.

Comment: How are you planning to clean the source code, with an editor? Which one? With a script? If so, can you use .NET regex?

Comment: I use grepWin to replace content in many file that match with regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is in C++, but you haven't said how you plan to replace the slashes: this could be in an IDE, with a script, or with other tools.

Here is a solution that will work Notepad++ (tested) using a search and replace in regex mode.

Search: `(?m)(?:^#include\s*"|\G)[^/"]*\K/`

Replace: `\`

**Explanation:**

```
(?m)(?:^#include\s*"|\G)[^/"]*\K/
```

- Use these options for the whole regular expression `(?m)`

  - ^$ &match at line breaks `m`
- Match the regular expression below `(?:^#include\s*"|\G)`

  - Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) `^#include\s*"`

    - Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) (line feed) `^`
    - Match the character string “#include” literally (case sensitive) `#include`
    - Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (ASCII space, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed) `\s*`

      - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`
    - Match the character “"” literally `"`
  - Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) `\G`

    - Assert position at the end of the previous match (the start of the string for the first attempt) `\G`
- Match any single character NOT present in the list “/"” `[^/"]*`

  - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`
- Keep the text matched so far out of the overall regex match `\K`
- Match the character “/” literally `/`

Comment: @StdAfx You're very welcome, glad to hear it works for you. :)